# OneHotEncoding an array of text with ML.NET

Tags: .net, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, ml.net

I have a class `InputData` as below

```
public class InputData
{
    public string[] TextFields { get; set; }
    public float[] NumericFields { get; set; }
}
```

When building the pipeline, I can easily convert `NumericFields` to numeric features with 1 line of code

```
var numFeatures = MlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("NumFeatures", nameof(InputData.NumericFields));
```

However I couldn't figure out a way to one-hot-encoding `TextFields`

According to the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.categoricalcatalog.onehotencoding, each text field needs to have its own property and then can be added as

```
MlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("TextField1", "TextField2" ....);
```

Is there a more elegant way to quickly OneHotEncoding an array of text fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work just fine:

```
mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("TextFeatures")
```

When one-hot encoding a **vector**, we have two options: 'bag', or 'indicator'. They are covered quite well in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.onehotencodingestimator?view=ml-dotnet).

In short, if you have K features and there is M distinct values in the dataset, with 'bag' option you will get a vector of counts of size M, and with 'indicator' you will get a vector of 0s and 1s of size K*M.

Comment: so what I need to do is ```mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("TextFeatures", "TextFeatures", OneHotEncodingEstimator.OutputKind.Bag);``` perfect answer to my problem, thanks, why there is no tutorial on this matter?